# Javascript, function chaining and events?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, node.js, floating-action-button

Digging into NodeJS I've come across (fab) which really impressed me. After watching Jed's presentation I understand how function chaining works but I'm left with one question: In case of a situation where an event can (but doesn't have to) occur such as in case of an HTTP listener, how does function chaining work?

For example, if I had the following pattern:

```
(listen, 8080)
    (write)
        ('test1')
        ('test2')
    ()
()
```

How would I write the listen function that it in case of an HTTP request the strings 'test1' and 'test2' get written to the client?

Answer (score 3):

For general solution to the problem of orchestration of async calls in javascript, please see https://github.com/tatumizer/mesh. It does parallelization and chaining automatically, based on knowledge of input and output parameters of each function. There's very detailed README file, with lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it is implemented in (fab) but something like what you explain can be implemented using promises and deferred objects. See the [CommonJS, I Promise](http://blip.tv/file/4306040/) talk by Kris Kowal. See also [Futures and promises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I make sure I'll watch the video. As for (fab), going through the source it appears to be pure function chaining, that is to say no promises or other mechanisms. As far as I managed to get through the whole thing it appears that the stream is paused and restarted. This is what Jed says too in his presentation. That given I still don't understand how an implementation would work because as in my example above the interpreter goes through instantaneously - no option to "stop at some point and wait for an event".